# Airflow config listener - Listen to all or just local host?

Tags: airflow

I'm configuring Airflow using PostgreSQL metadata database.
The [guide](https://medium.com/@taufiq_ibrahim/apache-airflow-installation-on-ubuntu-ddc087482c14) says to do the following:

Next, we configure `postgresql.conf`.

```
sudo nano /etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf
# — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — 
# CONNECTIONS AND AUTHENTICATION
# — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — 
# — Connection Settings -
#listen_addresses = ‘localhost’ # what IP address(es) to listen on;
listen_addresses = ‘*’ # for Airflow connection
// Restart the service
sudo service postgresql restart
```

I don't understand why Airflow needs that? Airflow schedule tasks. It doesn't not listen to triggers from the "outside world". Why is that definition needed? It sounds like a security risk.

Answer (score 1):

What you have linked to seems to be an unofficial guide from a user which setup PostgreSQL as a backend and used this article as a reminder / information source for others.

I think you are right, this seems insecure and there are no other measures setup. This could work in an internal network, but it would still be unsecure and not recommended.

Usually I'd rather use the official docs https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-connection.html and setup only neccessary IP addresses, SSL as well as solid authentication. See more on that here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.0/static/security.htm

Comment: Sadly, official docs are not "how to do it step by step" which is usually what first time users need. What are your recommendations for hba file ? The permitted IP are thous who are sign into the UI right? And listener only for localhost?

Comment: I'd work through the official docs (the security section) and try to work all aspects to be safe. It's many more things than the hba file.

Comment: I will but the security section won't answer the question of how to config the hba file.  I'm focusing my questions:  Who airflow needs to listen to? The permitted Ip list is for the UI login?